# Let $T: \Bbb R^3 → \Bbb R^2 $be a linear transformation defined by $T( x, y, z) = ( x + y, x - z)$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**: Let $T: \Bbb R^3 → \Bbb R^2 $be a linear transformation defined by $T( x, y, z) = ( x + y, x - z)$.  Then dimension of null space of $T$ is

(A) $1 $
(B) $2 $
(C) $0$
(D) none of these

**Solution** : We know that

$ \dim (\Bbb R^2) =\dim $(null space  ) $+\dim ($range  $T$)

$2 =$ dim (null space  ) +$2$

$0 =$ dim (null space  )

Am I doing right ??

Comment: No, $\dim(\mathbb{R}^3) = \dim(null\;T)+\dim(im\;T)$

Comment: I think take $dim$ of codomain

Comment: That's where you are wrong.

Comment: LaTeX tips: Do not use `\Bbb` it's a mathjax thing and won't work in actual LaTeX files.  Use `\mathbb` instead. E.g. `\mathbb R`: $\mathbb R$. You should use `\dim` to get $\dim$.  It's useful to use abbreviations like `\ker T` ($\ker T$) and `\operatorname{im} T` ($\operatorname{im} T$). Yes, LaTeX and mathjax don't come with a predefined `\im` and `\Im` gives the symbol for imaginary part of a complex number.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I get confused by rank nullity theorem of matrix where we use column of matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$ T(x,y,z) = (0,0) \iff x+y = 0 \text{ and } x-z = 0 \\ \iff x=z \text{ and } -x=y \\ \iff (x,y,z) = (x,-x,x)$$
It is now clear that a basis of the null space of $T$ is given by $\{(1,-1,1)\}$, i.e. its dimension is $1$.

Comment: What about the formula  used by me. In it we use $dim$ of domain set or codomain set

Comment: The problem is that if you want to use this formula, then you have to compute either the dimension of the null space or the dimension of the image. So if you have to do a calculus then do directly the good one. Just by using the formula you can in the best case give an lower bound, that is $Im(T) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ so $dim(\ker(T)) = dim(\mathbb{R}^3)- dim(Im(T)) \geq 1$... but this is not helping a lot if you don't show the exact dimension of the image...

Comment: In my last comment obviously $Im(T)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Rank nullity theorem** : For a linear map $T:V\rightarrow W$

$\text{dim}(\text{im} (T)) + \text{dim} (\text{ker} (T)) = \text{dim} (V)$

Just to look in another way :

Given $m,n\in \mathbb{R}$ Can you find $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$x+y=m;x-z=n$$

Do you think three unknowns with two equations always have solution?

Do you think this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Since $T(0,1,0)=(1,0)$ and $T(0,0,-1)=(0,1)$, you know that the image of $T$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the rank-nullity theorem makes you finish.

Note that the rank-nullity theorem tells you that, for a linear map $T\colon V\to W$,
$$
\dim V=\dim N(T)+\dim\operatorname{Im}(T)
$$
where $N(T)$ is the null space and $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is the image (or range) of $T$. All you can say involving the dimension of the codomain $W$ is that $\dim\operatorname{Im}(T)\le\dim W$. The relation expressed by the theorem has to do with the dimension of the *domain*.